# Outlook Deeplink calendar link not working

Tags: outlook, hyperlink, calendar

I have a script that writes an outlook calendar link that is included in registration e-mails for events. It recently has stopped working, though I've not changed anything in the script so I'm wondering if Outlook has changed something. The links look like this: `https://outlook.office.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose?rru=addevent&path=/calendar/action/compose&startdt=2023-08-15T15%3A00%3A00-07%3A00&enddt=2023-08-15T16%3A00%3A00-07%3A00&ctz=(GMT-07:00) America/Los_Angeles&location=https://xxxxx.zoom.us/w/12345678901?tk=EeAST8NNc7Id2BZFVQwCXeF7sxxhQnx_4YM.DQMAAAAUAKtDZxY2VnVjUHdrR1R5eURXQWhYRUItQjdnAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&pwd=Q0xLNnFGTHhTEZ0QUZxZz09&subject=training`
When an Outlook user would click the link, it would create a calendar invite in the their web browser. However, sometime in the very recent past, the behavior has changed. It will still open a browser window to outlook, but it just results in a gif of an outlook envelope. Does anyone have any ideas on what I need to change?

Thanks,

Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be with /0. Try to deep dive into it.

https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/discussions/47